# Replace part of text in a cell case sensitive

Tags: excel, vba

This seems easy but I couldn't find an answer.

Each solution either replaced part of the cell, or replaced case sensitive but then the replace text had to equal the value in the cell

```
If InStr(1, CurColumnName, ReplaceFrom, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then 
'wksC.Range(CurColumnLetter & "1").Value = Replace(CurColumnName, ReplaceFrom, ReplaceTo)
wksC.Range(CurColumnLetter & "1").Replace what:=ReplaceFrom, replacement:=ReplaceTo, MatchCase:=True 
End If
```

Let's say my `CurColumnName` is `Mp3npi`, my `ReplaceFrom` is `npi`, my `ReplaceTo` is `NPI`.

The code goes into the loop, goes through the `range.replace`, but the cell isn't replaced, it remains as is.

Comment: Why not replace in the entire column in one go? `npi==>NPI` with case sensitive?

Comment: what do you mean? can you give an example? i thought i am replacing it on 1 go, i'm looking for any column that has NPI and replacing it with upper  case.

Comment: ok i see what you meant. these are headers i'm replacing, not the entire column, so just the first row has to be replaced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the official documentation of the [Range.Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) it says:

> The settings for `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, `MatchCase`, and `MatchByte` are saved each time you use this method. If you don't specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used.

So that means if you don't specify all of them, Excel uses what ever was used before (either by VBA or by the user interface *Find/Replace*). There is no default value for the parameters you can rely on. Therefore you get random results depending on what your user selected before. So you **always** have to specify at least those mentioned parameters or your code is not reliable.

```
wksC.Columns(CurColumnLetter).Replace What:=ReplaceFrom, Replacement:=ReplaceTo, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, MatchByte:=True
```

This would replace `npi` into `NPI` in the entire column `CurColumnLetter` at once where `npi` doesn't need to be the entire cell value but a part (`xlPart`) of it.

Actually the same issue applies to the `Find` method as well, where parameters need to be specified to make it reliable.